# How can I distinct count values in a column in R

Tags: r, select, distinct

I have something like this:

```
# A tibble: 24,288 x 1
```

`Country/Region`
   
  Afghanistan
  Albania
  Algeria
  Andorra
  Angola
  Antigua and Barbuda
  Argentina
  Armenia
  Australia
  Australia

## ... with 24,278 more rows

How can I count the different values in this tibble?

Comment: Do you need `n_distinct(df$\`Country/Region\`)` or `length(unique(df$\`Country/Region\`))` or `uniqueN(df$\`Country/Region\`)` ? All of them count distinct values in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `count` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   count(`Country/Region`)
```

Comment: there are two ore more rows with same values. I want to do a distinct count. How can I do that?

Comment: @Leko The `count` will gives the distinct  frequency count. Sorry, didn't understand your question

Comment: It was something wrong with my code so the count function wasn't working. it works with tydiverse package:

select () %>%
  distinct()

thank u for help.

Comment: @Leko it is possible that `count` is masked from some other package `count` function.  In that case, you can speciify the package with `dplyr::count(`Country/Region`)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sqldf solution:

```
textFile <- "Country_Region
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
Antigua and Barbuda Argentina
Armenia
Australia
Australia"

data <- read.csv(text = textFile,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select count(distinct Country_Region) from data")
```

...and the result:

```
> sqldf("select count(distinct Country_Region) from data")
  count(distinct Country_Region)
1                              8
>
```